# inherited_resources gives wrong resource_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, inherited-resources

I'm using Rails 3.2.16 and inherited_resources 1.4.1. I needed a fast ad custom admin, so I used this post as example (it's still valid for rails 3.2):

http://iain.nl/backends-in-rails-3-1

This is what my routes files looks like:

```
  namespace :backend do
    root to: 'conferences#index'
    resources :conferences do
      resources :talks
      resources :sponsors
    end
  end
```

My `Backend::ConferencesController` and `Backend::SponsorsController` they both inherit from `Backend::ResourceController` as detailed in the blog post.

The problem I find is that whenever I go to the `Sponsors` index page, I get a `NoMethodError`:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `backend_sponsor_path' for #<Backend::SponsorsController:0x007fa588113e08>
```

The weird thing it that the `resource_path` method is trying to find `backend_sponsor_path` instead of `backend_conference_sponsor_path` as declared in the routes.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Shouldn't `inherited_resources` be able to find the correct path?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, problem has been solved by adding `belongs_to :conference` to the `SponsorsController`:

```
class Backend::SponsorsController < Backend::ResourceController
  belongs_to :conference
end
```

Now routes are generated as expected! :)